# What type of Java Project is Netflix-Graph

Tags: java, open-source, project-management, netflix

Java has various project types and the worse thing is that I'm a newbie in Java.

Netflix hosts a open-source project on GitHub: [github.com/Netflix/netflix-graph/](https://github.com/Netflix/netflix-graph/).

I want to know which kind/type of project it is ? Console, EE, or ....?
Also, how can such projects be created or any reference to better analogy of various project types ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a library which you can include in your Java project to work with graphs. As such, it is similar in "type" as a JSON parser or an HTTP client library.

It is not an application that you run by itself.

It does not seem to have any special dependencies, so that you can probably use it in all kinds of Java applications, most likely even on Android.

Comment: Well i understood your point, but can you elaborate upon how to create such libs please ? I mean like we have <code>Class Library Project</code> in .NET, is there something in Java or we have to manually do it.

Comment: Nothing special to do, really. All you have to do is package that code up in a jar file.